# Can not pass eventName and callback to addEventListener because of 'No overload matches this call'

Tags: javascript, typescript, event-listener

I am trying to add event listener to the input element stored inside class in method of this class which takes props object which contains **`eventName`** and **`callback`**.

```js
public setTextFieldInputListener({ eventName, callback }: TextFieldListenerProps): void {
    this.input.addEventListener(eventName, callback);
}
```

This listener props object is a union type of two interfaces *`BlurTextFieldCallbackProps`* *`InputTextFieldCallbackProps`*

```js
export type TextFieldListenerProps = BlurTextFieldListenerProps | InputTextFieldListenerProps;

export interface BaseTextFieldListenerProps {
    eventName: Extract<keyof GlobalEventHandlersEventMap, 'blur' | 'input'>;
    callback(e?: FocusEvent | Event): void;
}

export interface BlurTextFieldListenerProps extends BaseTextFieldListenerProps {
    eventName: Extract<keyof GlobalEventHandlersEventMap, 'blur'>;
    callback(e?: FocusEvent): void;
}

export interface InputTextFieldListenerProps extends BaseTextFieldListenerProps {
    eventName: Extract<keyof GlobalEventHandlersEventMap, 'input'>;
    callback(e?: Event): void;
}
```

Then when I am trying to assign this **`eventName`** and **`callback`**, I am getting this error:

> TS2769: No overload matches this call.
> Overload 1 of 2, '(type: "input" | "blur", listener: (this: HTMLInputElement, ev: Event | FocusEvent) => any, options?: boolean | AddEventListenerOptions | undefined): void', gave the following error.
> Argument of type '((e?: InputEvent | undefined) => void) | ((e?: FocusEvent | undefined) => void)' is not assignable to parameter of type '(this: HTMLInputElement, ev: Event | FocusEvent) => any'. ...

On the beginning I was wondering it can be a problem if **`eventName`** will be a `'blur'` and event will be a *`FocusEvent`* so I created a typeguard:

```js
export function isBlurTextFieldProps(value: BaseTextFieldListenerProps): value is BlurTextFieldListenerProps {
    return value.eventName === 'blur';
}
```

And I changed method responsible for setting eventListener:

```js
public setTextFieldInputListener(listenerProps: TextFieldListenerProps): void {
    if (isBlurTextFieldProps(listenerProps)) {
        this.input.addEventListener(listenerProps.eventName, listenerProps.callback);
    }
}
```

but this didn't helped at all :/

My question is:

- Why I am getting this error ?
- How can I fix it still keeping strong types ? (I know that I can fix this with `any` but I do not want to use `any`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by using generic `<K>addEventListener` method. K refers to type of event name (`'blur'`, `'input'`).

```js
public setTextFieldInputListener(listenerProps: TextFieldListenerProps): void {
    if (isOnBlurTextFieldProps(listenerProps)) {
        this.input.addEventListener<'blur'>(listenerProps.eventName, listenerProps.callback.bind(this));
    } else if (isOnInputTextFieldProps(listenerProps)) {
        this.input.addEventListener<'input'>(listenerProps.eventName, listenerProps.callback.bind(this));
    }
}
```

Comment: Any idea why this solves the problem?